# remove LCK file from /data/local/tmp when app starts

Tags: android

How can I remove a LCK file from /data/local/tmp in android when app starts? The USB serial port detection on the device creates a LCK file in /data/local/tmp when the app starts. However, this prevents the device from opening a serial port connection the next time the app is launched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by closing the USB SerialPort connection when the activity ends.